# Magento Capture with Authorize.net

Tags: magento-1.7, authorize.net

I am using the Magento 1.7.0.2 and am told by Authorize.net that Magento does not include the original authorization transaction ID in the capture calls. The captures are going through but I am left with pre-auth calls that eventually drop off, rather than capturing funds on the original pre-auth transaction.

Is there any way to have Magento do a capture and send in the original transaction ID? The data is there in Magento since you can see the parent transaction ID but where do I go to add this into the capture call so Auth.net can be happy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

an earlier version has it in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php` on approximately line ~1325 in the function `_generateTransactionId` which should be called during capture while doing the invoicing.

just fyi, if you have a transaction id equal to `0` this means you have your `authorizenet` payment method settings set to `test mode`: `yes`, just turn it off and you should be fine assuming it is a test account.  You don't need test mode on a test account.  If this is not the issue then I am not certain what the issue is as Magento should do this on it's own.

the following stack trace is a result of when the transaction id is zero when capturing a pre authorized transaction...

```
#0 .../app/code/local/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(535): Mage->throwException('Gateway error: The ccnumber field is required REFID:...')
#1 .../app/code/local/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(345): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->_place(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment, '5060.98', 'AUTH_CAPTURE')
#2 .../app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(290): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->capture(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment, '5060.98')
#3 .../app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(268): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice)
#4 .../app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice/Api.php(236): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
...
...
...
```